# Why Expo Performance Monitor not shown RAM?

Tags: react-native

I want to see how much RAM my app costs using  Expo Performance Monitor in Android Emulator! So i opened this when i click **ctrl+M** in my elulator (Android) and then press **Show Performance Monitor**  But it show only this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf2UN.png). How can i fix that? Sorry for myy bad english